# How to mock global Vue.js variable in JEST test

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocking, vuejs2, jestjs

I have a global property/variable with my app urls:

```
Vue.prototype.$apiUrls = {
  root: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  api: 'api/v1/'
  // etc.  
}
```

I use it inside my components as axios request:

```
axios.get(`${this.$apiUrls.root}${this.$apiUrls.api}/users/`)
```

Now I want to test my component's code, I've mocked `axios` already, but still I receive an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$apiUrls' of undefined
```

I've tried to define/mock this property inside each test and/or in JEST's setup file, like e.g.

```
global.$apiUrls = {...}
// or
Vue.prototype.$apiUrls = {...}
// or
Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {$apiUrls: {...}})
```

I've also tried mocking it to `window` or `this` (yeah, thats silly), but with no success - I still receive that error - please help.

Comment: Are you also using the `vue-test-utils` ?

Comment: @Derek not in this particular project, but I'm open to start using it here as well if necessary ;)

Comment: What concerns me is part of the documentation says this: `Note some plugins, like Vue Router, add read-only properties to the global Vue constructor. This makes it impossible to reinstall the plugin on a localVue constructor, or add mocks for these read-only properties`

Comment: hmn but I think that may refer if I would like to mock `$router` prop, or if I use something like `Vue.use(myPluginWithApiUrlProperty)` (but not sure)

Comment: Did you solve this? Let me know if you need anything clarifying!

Comment: @xenetics yes, thanks you your (and @Aldarund) solutions I've found a silly mistake in my code and adjusted everything to your tips, thank You!

Comment: Great! All the best with your TDD experience - it's definitely the best way to develop software, imo!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is two ways to achieve this. One is using the `Config` option, as mentioned by @Aldarund. You can read about it [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#config).

If you are using Jest, I recommend doing this in the `jest.init.js` file:

```
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'

config.mocks['$apiUrls'] = {
  'some/endpoint'
}
```

Then add this to the `jest` section of your `package.json`:

```
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/jest.init.js"
]
```

Now it is globally mocked. If you want to do this on a per test basis, you can use the `mocks` mounting option:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo, {
  mocks: {
    $apiUrls: 'some/endpoint'
  }
})
```

Hopefully this helps!

If you are interested I am compiling a collection of simple guides on how to test Vue components [here](https://github.com/lmiller1990/vue-testing-handbook). It's under development, but feel free to ask make an issue if you need help with other related things to testing Vue components.

Comment: This no longer works. You need to do `import {config} from "@vue/test-utils"`. See https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#config

Comment: @xenetics you should have acknowledged Artur's comment or answer since you just updated yours based on his.

Comment: for version 2.0.0.rc-18 its config.global.mocks['$some'] = /* custom code */

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the answers above work anymore (in 2020).

Here's what worked for me:

### For vue-test-utils 1.x.x (Vue 2)

1. Create a new file, name it eg. `jest.init.js`
2. Give it the following content:

```js
import { config } from "@vue/test-utils";
config.mocks["yourGlobalProperty"] = label => label; //you can replace it with your own mock
```

3. Add this to your `jest.config.js` (actually write "rootDir", don't replace anything with a real path)

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/jest.init.js"]
}
```

These files will be only ran before jest runs unit tests.

Note that I'm importing `{config}`, not the default export. I don't know why the default didn't work for me. [Even the documentation for vue test utils doesn't import the default export anymore](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#config)

Also make sure you're not trying to import from the old `vue-test-utils` package. (The new one is `@vue/test-utils`)

#### For @vue/test-utils 2.x.x (vue-test-utils-next) (Vue 3)

Follow steps like for 1.x.x above, but in step two, do this instead:

```
import { config } from "@vue/test-utils"; //2.0.0-beta.5
config.global.mocks = {
  yourGlobalProperty: label => label
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [vue-test-utils beta 15](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/325#issuecomment-383098083) and later.

Here [docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/config.html#mocks)

And some example would be:

```
import VueTestUtils from '@vue/test-utils'

VueTestUtils.config.mocks['$apiUrls'] = {
  ...
}
```